# RSpec spec fails when invoked via "rake spec", passes when invoked via "spec spec"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

One of my specs fails when I run it via "rake spec" but passes when I use the RSpec executable "spec".
The spec fails when I use a url helper in a ActionMailer view. The error message is:

```
auction_url failed to generate from {:action=>"show", :state=>"asd", :slug=>"asd", :controller=>"auctions"}, expected: {:action=>"show", :controller=>"auctions"}, diff: {:state=>"asd", :slug=>"asd"}
```

:state and :slug are required attributes for the url, though.
The route looks like this:

```
map.auction ':state/:slug', :controller => 'auctions', :action => 'show'
```

I set the host, which is needed to use the url helpers in ActionMailer views, in the environment files:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = 'myhost.com'
```

What could be the problem?
Why is "rake spec" behaving differently from "spec spec"?
Anything that is loaded/not loaded when using one or the other?

Comment: It even works when invoked via "ruby spec/..." so it must be something with my rake environment / Rakefile.
The contents of my Rakefile haven't been changed from the standard stuff Rails gave me:

require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'tasks/rails'

Please, anyone, I'm losing my mind over this!

Comment: My answer was deleted (courtesy of @bhargav-rao) as a duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701298/rspec-spec-rake-spec-gives-different-result/41877864#41877864

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a bit old, but anyway - I just ran into the same problem, not for the first time either. Then, when I started inserting debug statements into the failing spec to figure out what was going on - rake spec worked again. So I suspect some sort of caching going on when spec is involved with rake. If this occurs again, maybe try running

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

or even

```
rake tmp:clear
```