# Rspec capybara spec fails when invoked via 'rake spec' but passes when invoked via 'rspec spec'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I've tried the answers to these questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364600/rspec-spec-fails-when-invoked-via-rake-spec-passes-when-invoked-via-spec-spe), [2](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/182494). The first one indicates it might be a caching issue (and suggests running `rake tmp:clear`). The second one suggests forcing `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'` in `spec_helper.rb` since rake is run in 'development'. I've also tried removing the vcr gem completely, but this has no effect either.

This [comment](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/208#issuecomment-413114) gives more details on how the problem might be due to a dirty environment (since rake starts in 'development', but rspec is run in 'test').

The spec in question uses capybara and capybara-webkit. It passes when run via `bundle exec rake spec:requests` but fails when it's run in the suite via `bundle exec rake`. The html that capybara sees is different in both cases, and when run in the suite it doesn't see the element `#movie_imdb_id`.

I'm using gem versions `rspec (2.11.0)`, `capybara (1.1.3)`, and `capybara-webkit (0.12.1)`.

Rspec message:

```
Failures:

  1) Imdb credits get credits should have a credits table
     Failure/Error: wait_until { page.find('#movie_imdb_id').visible? }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "#movie_imdb_id"
     # (eval):2:in `find'
     # ./spec/requests/imdb_credits_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/imdb_credits_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'paper_trail'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'vcr'
require 'imdb_patch'
require 'capybara/rails'
# require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/webkit'

ENV['APP_DOMAIN'] = 'www.example.com'
ENV['DOMAIN'] = 'example.com'

# Require the fanatic and food factories
require Fanatic::Engine.config.root + 'spec/factories'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/factories/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  config.include PostsHelper
  config.include SpecHelpers

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  #config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    PaperTrail.enabled = false
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    Rails.cache.clear
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    Warden.test_reset!
  end

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end

VCR.configure do |c|
  c.ignore_localhost = true
  c.hook_into :fakeweb
  c.cassette_library_dir = Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/vcr_cassettes')
end
```

spec/requests/imdb_credits_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Imdb credits', :js => true do
  before(:each) do
    login_as_admin

    visit '/admin/movie/new'
    Rails.logger.debug page.html.to_yaml
    wait_until { page.find('#movie_imdb_id').visible? }

    fill_in 'Title',   :with => 'Batman'
    fill_in 'Imdb id', :with => '0096895'

    VCR.use_cassette('imdb_get', :match_requests_on => [get_matcher]) do
      click_button 'Fetch Imdb credits'
      wait_until { page.find('table#imdb_credits').visible? }
    end
  end

  describe 'get credits' do

    it 'should have a credits table' do
      page.should have_selector('table#imdb_credits')
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Does `bundle exec rspec spec` work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Benjamin. Yes it does.

Comment: @BenjaminTan I'd still like to be able to run `bundle exec rake`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually the gem `rails_admin` and how it was interacting with rake. It was fixed by adding the following to `spec_helper.rb`:

```
ENV['SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER'] = 'false'
```