# Rspec spec & Rake spec gives different result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

This seems to be mostly asked question, I have an application when run in both `rake spec` and `rspec` the output seems to be different. When rspec spec -p command is used 0 failures message is displayed while when rake spec is used few errors are displayed.

Comment: Can you provide more details like what is your rake output?

Comment: after running rspec spec -p 0 failures while rake spec gives me errors and its always changing 1 failure, 3 failures and sometime no failure pls help, is rspec better than rake spec? don know abt these stuffs pls help :-)

Comment: What errors specifically?  Without that information it's gonna be pretty difficult for people to help.

Comment: thx for ur reply the error that i am coming across is ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Answer (score 0):

When you run `$ bundle exec rspec # (defaults to spec)`, all the files in the `./spec` directory are executed.

When you run `$ bundle exec rake spec`, you're executing all of the rake tasks named `'spec'` from all the gems and from their dependencies.

Also the environment under which tests are executed may vary accordingly to those files. Don't wonder if you face different outputs.